# NSURLConnection not downloading

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

The functions in JSONDownload.m

```
-(void)downloadEntries{
    NSString *urlString = @"https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=4431/json";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    [self.webData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(nonnull NSData *)data{
    [self.webData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSError *error;
    self.dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.webData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

-(NSString *)returnName: (NSInteger)index{
    NSArray *entry = [self entryArray];
    NSDictionary *indexDictionary = [entry objectAtIndex:index];
    NSDictionary *nameDictionary = [indexDictionary objectForKey:@"im:name"];
    NSString *nameOfMovie = [nameDictionary objectForKey:@"label"];
    return nameOfMovie;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfEntries{
    NSDictionary *feed = [self dictionary];
    NSArray *entry = [feed objectForKey:@"entry"];
    return [entry count];
}
```

which is called by another class FeedEntry.m

```
- (void)recieveEntries{
    JSONDownload *download = [JSONDownload sharedInstance];
    [download downloadEntries]; // calling method

    NSInteger numberOfEntries = [download numberOfEntries]; //calling method

    for (int index = 0; index < numberOfEntries; index++) {

        self.name = [download returnName:index]; //calling method 
        NSLog(@"%@",self.name);
    }
}
```

However on tracing I found that connectionDidFinishLoading: is not called and hence **dictionary** property in that fucntion is not initialised. Thus I'm getting numberOfEntries as 0 and the loop is not executed. What should be done?

Comment: Have you implemented the other (required) delegate methods `didReceiveResponse` and `didReceiveData`? Anyway calling `numberOfEntries` after `downloadEntries` will always return 0 due to the asynchronous behavior of the connection.

Comment: You need a completion handler or a delegate method which is invoked in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method to inform `FeedEntry` that data is available.

Comment: @vadian how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a completion handler because `NSURLConnection` works asynchronously.

in `FeedEntry.h` define a block type and a `completion` property

```
typedef void (^ConnectionCompletion)(NSDictionary *data, NSError *error);

@property (nonatomic, copy) ConnectionCompletion completion;
```

In `FeedEntry.m` change `downloadEntries` to

```
- (void)downloadEntriesWithCompletion:(ConnectionCompletion)completion{
    self.completion = completion;
    NSString *urlString = @"https://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topmovies/limit=50/genre=4431/json";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

and change `connectionDidFinishLoading` to

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSError *error;
    self.dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.webData options:0 error:&error];
    self.completion(self.dictionary, error);
}
```

The completion handler returns the dictionary as well as a potential serialization error.

Now call the method with

```
JSONDownload *download = [JSONDownload sharedInstance];
[download downloadEntriesWithCompletion:^(NSDictionary *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } else {
       NSInteger numberOfEntries = [download numberOfEntries]; //calling method
       for (int index = 0; index < numberOfEntries; index++) {
         self.name = [download returnName:index]; //calling method 
         NSLog(@"%@",self.artist);
       }
     }
 }];
```

The returned parameters in the completion handler are just an example. You could pass also the shared instance or whatever you need.

You should also implement `connectionDidFailWithError` and call the completion handler also there to return `nil` and the error.

Comment: I just realised I have to learn so much about blocks. Thanks for the code. It seem to be working now. However `didReceiveData:` is showing 0 key/value pair and in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` its throwing an exception saying `data parameter is nil`. I checked the syntax but everything seems to be in proper order.

Comment: is `webData` initialized as `[NSMutabledata data]`?